# Enable Ivy cache persistence on Travis CI

Tags: caching, travis-ci, ivy

I'm a beginner on Travis CI and i'm trying to optimize my build.
I use Apache Ivy as dependency manager. By default, Ivy put the cache into `~/.ivy2` directory.
In order to avoid download of dependencies on each build, I set the `cache` element on my `.travis.yml` file as following:

```
cache:
   directories:
   - ~/.ivy2
```

I also tried:

```
cache:
   directories:
   - $HOME/.ivy2
```

with no luck. 
The dependencies are not retrieved from cache but downloaded every time, as the Ivy log say:

```
[ivy:retrieve] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.8.2/gwt-user-2.8.2.jar ...
[ivy:retrieve] ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................... (15915kB)
[ivy:retrieve]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.google.gwt#gwt-user;2.8.2!gwt-user.jar (731ms)
```

I also tried to list recursively (`ls -R ~/.ivy2`) the Ivy cache dir in `before_script` but i get no output.
May you please tell me what should I do to make the cache effective?

Answer (score 0):

-To avoid unnecessary cache updates

```
before_cache:
  # Cleanup the cached directories to avoid unnecessary cache updates
  - find $HOME/.ivy2/cache -name "ivydata-*.properties" -print -delete
```

-These directories are cached.

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
```